# When SystemUI loads in Android Boot

Tags: android, android-source, boot, android-statusbar

How to know when the system UI loads in `Android` boot process? 
Where exactly the status bar and navigation bar view draws?
As `SystemUI` is a privileged app so is it loading before the start of a launcher app (Home screen)? 
I am not sure. Any suggestion is welcome.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

*Below is a chain of briefly explained steps that hopefully shed some light on the sequence of "loading" the system UI components at boot time. I'll demonstrate it on `Android` 4.2, although the sequence is quite similar for the other versions.*

- When `SystemServer` is "done" with the core system services, [including `StatusBarManagerService`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.2.1_r1.2/com/android/server/SystemServer.java#427) *, it informs the 3rd party code that the [system is ready](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.2.1_r1.2/com/android/server/SystemServer.java#861) and starts the system UI (*line 870*), or more precise, [`SystemUIService`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.2.1_r1.2/com/android/systemui/SystemUIService.java#SystemUIService) in the `com.android.systemui` package **.
- `SystemUIService` is just an `Android` [application component](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) whose [`onCreate()`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.2.1_r1.2/com/android/systemui/SystemUIService.java#70) method starts/initializes UI components and stores references to the components in the `mServices[]` array of [`SystemUI`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.2.1_r1.2/com/android/systemui/SystemUI.java#25) type. The 1st element (`mServices[0]`) is either the status bar or system bar (status + nav bar).
- [`BaseStatusBar`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.2.1_r1.2/com/android/systemui/statusbar/BaseStatusBar.java#BaseStatusBar), the implementation of the abstract `SystemUI` class, does some UI stuff (like adding views to `WindowManager` etc.). Additionally it declares a range of abstract UI-related methods (e.g. [`createAndAddWindows()`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.2.1_r1.2/com/android/systemui/statusbar/BaseStatusBar.java#127)) to be implemented by subclasses, e.g. [`PhoneStatusBar`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.2.1_r1.2/com/android/systemui/statusbar/phone/PhoneStatusBar.java#PhoneStatusBar).
- The status bar and navigation bar aren't composed of a single view. Such subclasses of `BaseStatusBar` as `PhoneStatusBar`, `TabletStatusBar` etc. *** deal with multiple classes basically subclassed from [`View`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html) whose drawing (so does status bar's drawing) takes place in the [`onDraw()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onDraw(android.graphics.Canvas)) method.
- **Important note:** on system boot the status bar (and software navigation bar) won't be visible until the launcher `Activity`'s (the one with [`android.intent.category.HOME`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#CATEGORY_HOME)) `onResume()` method returns (and bootanimation exits) despite the fact all the views the status bar is composed of have already been laid out.

---

<sup>*AOSP*:
 * *frameworks/base/services/java/com/android/server/* 

 ** *frameworks/base/packages/SystemUI/src/com/android/systemui/SystemUIService.java*  
 *** *frameworks/base/packages/SystemUI/src/com/android/systemui/statusbar/*</sup>

Answer (score 1):

SystemUI is one of the first apps which starts. Because everything like the Lockscreen, Notifications, the Statusbar or the recent apps view are part of SystemUI. So yeah the SystemUI starts before your launcher is started