# How to hide status bar in AOSP build

Tags: android-source

I'd like to hide/remove the status bar (i.e the top bar containing clock, notifications,...) in my custom AOSP image.

Do you know if it's practically possible ? And how ?

Comment: Declare and define the imageview(or whatever) and then use object.setvisibility(View.GONE);

Comment: Would [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40754508/3290339) help in  not starting `SystemUIService`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The status bar layout is defined in [`frameworks/base/packages/SystemUI/res/layout/status_bar.xml`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/packages/SystemUI/res/layout/status_bar.xml):

```
<com.android.systemui.statusbar.phone.PhoneStatusBarView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:systemui="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.android.systemui"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/status_bar_height"
    android:id="@+id/status_bar"
    android:background="@drawable/system_bar_background"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:descendantFocusability="afterDescendants"
    >

    <!-- […] -->

</com.android.systemui.statusbar.phone.PhoneStatusBarView>
```

You could try to set the `height` of `com.android.systemui.statusbar.phone.PhoneStatusBarView` to `0dp` (defined by `status_bar_height` in [`frameworks/base/core/res/res/values/dimens.xml`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/res/res/values/dimens.xml#34)) or its `visibility` to `gone`.

Here is a link to a guide on xda-developers that explains how to "hack" SystemUI.apk and framework-res.apk to hide the status bar: [[GUIDE] Hide Status Bar and still being able to expand it on Jelly Bean](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?p=37466852#post37466852).
It may be useful to know which resources to modify.